# principle in equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't understand some principle, when there is an equation and I have to multiple in order to remove the denominator.

$$\frac{7}{25x^2+20x+4} + \frac{x-1}{25x^2-4} = \frac{1}{5x+2}$$

$$\frac{7}{(5x+2)^2} + \frac{x-1}{(5x-2)(5x+2)} = \frac{1}{5x+2}$$

in this stage, when I multiply by $(5x-2)(5x+2)$ , I got wrong answer.
when I multiply by $(5x+2)^2(5x-2)$ I got right answer.

I don't understand why I have to multiply by $(5x+2)^2$ , why $(5x+2)$ alone isn't enough ?

Comment: What happened when you multiplied by $(5x-2)(5x+2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically multiplying with $(5x+2)$ is not enough because

$$\frac{7}{(5x+2)^2} \cdot (5x+2) = \frac{7\cdot (5x+2)}{(5x+2)\cdot (5x+2)} = \frac{7}{(5x+2)}$$

However, we want to multiply all denominators out.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to transform all fractions so they have the same denominator, using the fact that
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{ac}{bc}
$$
Then we can use another fact about fractions: $\frac{A}{C}=\frac{B}{C}$ if and only if $A=B$. This can be done in one step, often called “clearing denominators”, provided we can find a factor that makes *all* denominators the same. Since they are
$$
(5x+2)^2\qquad(5x-2)(5x+2)\qquad(5x+2)
$$
we need to use
$$
(5x+2)^2(5x-2)
$$
The explicit steps would be
\begin{gather}
\frac{7}{25x^2+20x+4} + \frac{x-1}{25x^2-4} = \frac{1}{5x+2}\\[10px]
\frac{7}{(5x+2)^2} + \frac{x-1}{(5x-2)(5x+2)} = \frac{1}{5x+2}\\[10px]
\frac{7}{(5x+2)^2}\frac{5x-2}{5x-2} + 
  \frac{x-1}{(5x-2)(5x+2)}\frac{5x+2}{5x+2} =
  \frac{1}{5x+2}\frac{(5x-2)(5x+2)}{(5x-2)(5x+2)}\\[10px]
\frac{7(5x-2)+(x-1)(5x+2)}{(5x-2)(5x+2)^2} =
  \frac{(5x-2)(5x+2)}{(5x-2)(5x+2)^2}
\end{gather}
and now both sides have the same denominators, so the equation is equivalent to
$$
7(5x-2)+(x-1)(5x-2)=(5x-2)(5x+2)
$$
(with the added condition that $(5x-2)(5x+2)^2\ne0$, of course).

The same result can be obtained by directly multiplying both sides of the equation by $(5x-2)(5x+2)^2$ (and adding the condition this is non zero). Just multiplying by $(5x-2)(5x+2)$ would leave a denominator $5x+2$ in the first term.